# $f$ is $\mu$-measurable $\Rightarrow$ $\textrm{sgn}f$ is $\mu$-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to prove the following claim

**Claim:** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. If $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is $\mu$-measurable, then $\textrm{f}$ is $\mu$-measurable.

- Here a function $f$ is called **$\mu$-measurable** if there exists a
  sequence of simple functions on $\Sigma$ $(\varphi_n)$ such that
  $\varphi_n \to f$ almost everywhere.
- We define $\textrm{sgn}(z) := z/|z|$ for $z \neq 0$ and $\textrm{sgn}(z) := 0$
  for $z = 0$.

---

This was just mentioned off-the-cuff in lecture as part of another proof. So I imagine it's not too difficult to see. Still, I haven't been able to prove it to myself or find anything on Stack Overflow about it.

---

**My work so far:**

I think I want to show the following:

**Want to show:** Let $(\varphi_n)$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $\varphi_n \to f$ almost everywhere, with $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$. Then $\textrm{sgn}(\varphi_n) \to \textrm{sgn}(f)$ almost everywhere.

We let $\varphi_n \to f$ pointwise on $\Omega \setminus N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$ and take an $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N$.

It suffices to show that $|\textrm{sgn}(\varphi_n(\omega)) - \textrm{sgn}(f(\omega))| \to 0$.

**Case 1:** $f(\omega) \neq 0$.

$|\varphi_n(\omega) - f(\omega)| \to 0 \Rightarrow \Big||\varphi_n(\omega)| - |f(\omega)|\Big| \to 0 \Rightarrow \Big| \frac{|\varphi_n(\omega)|}{f(\omega)} - \text{sgn}(f(\omega)) \Big| \to 0$.

Not sure where to go from here. I imagine I take a subsequence $(\varphi_{k(n)})$ that with no zero elements and show that $\frac{|\varphi_{k(n)}(\omega)|}{\varphi_{k(n)}(\omega)} \to \frac{|\varphi_n(\omega)|}{f(\omega)}$ and then use this to get the convergence I want.

**Case 2:** $f(\omega) = 0$. Here I need to show $\text{sgn}(\varphi_n(\omega)) \to 0$. If $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi_n(\omega) = 0$ $\forall n \geq M$, then I'm done. Otherwise, I'm not quite sure. Maybe I need to take a subsequence of nonzero $(\varphi_{k(n)}(\omega))$ and show $\text{sgn}(\varphi_{k(n)}(\omega)) \to 0$.

Comment: Uhm... If the domain is $\Bbb C$, then the image of $\operatorname{sgn}$ is not $\{0,1\}$, but $\{0\}\cup S^1$ (and I'd rather define it as $z/\lvert z\rvert$ for $z\ne 0$ because it makes more sense). If the domain is $\Bbb R$, then the image is $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Even on $\mathbb R$, It's not true that $sgn(f_n)\to sgn(f)$. Take $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$. Then $f_n(x)\to 0=:f$ for all $x$ but $sgn(f_n)\to 1$ a.e. $\neq sgn(f)=0$

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I corrected the definition of $\text{sgn}$. Thanks.

Comment: @Surb Oh, yeah. Then my strategy (WTS: ...) was clearly off. Any ideas for showing the claim here?

Comment: You have that $sgn(f)(z)=\frac{f(z)}{|f(z)|}\boldsymbol 1_{\{f(z)\neq 0\}}$ that is a product and quotient of measurable function. Then it's measurable.